# Excel same value but diffrent

Tags: excel, csv

I have a very strange problem, until confused I want to explain how
so the story is I want to upload the xlsx file to an online shop like to update the price
But it always fails, Rows 2 and 3 look the same, but if I upload row 2 it has an error but if I upload row 3 there is no problem.
Actually, what's the problem, how come it's so weird, the text is the same but one is correct and one makes an error.
At first I thought it was because of the format, I cleared the format but it still doesn't work, even if I use row number 3 but the format is strange it's not a problem, I typed manually it's not a problem,
It's the same if I copy text from csv and paste it into xlsx it also has an error
This xlsx file is from converting csv file and splicing it with kutools
[image]

Comment: Did you check for invisible Unicode characters?

Comment: @SamuNemeth No, how do i check it sir?

Comment: One way is to copy into a text editor like Notepad++ and toggle showing non-printable characters. Another is to just retype the text manually in each cell.

Comment: @ApplePie I already lookin into notepad++ i turn on show all symbol, but i cant see the diffrent

Comment: What is the complete actual error message?

Comment: Can you share a sample of the file so people can investigate?